# Both the Software Updater and apt-get update gives me this error. I've tried changing my primary server which didn't work

Tags: upgrade, software-rec, elementary-os

I believe I may have fiddled with the sources.. Is there any way to fix this issue.

`W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to https://launchpad.net/~versable/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-update, this ppa does not have packages for 14.04 (aka trusty).

If you are running Ubuntu <14.04 than replace trusty with yours distribution name again. Else try to use https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable, which gives following lines:

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu trusty main`

If you don't use Elementary OS (but vanilla Ubuntu) than simply kill these lines.

These are in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.